# Can't set LevelRangeFilter for log4j

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I am using this property file to setup log4j in Spring:

```
log4j.appender.EMAIL=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.EMAIL.filter=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.EMAIL.filter.levelMin=FATAL
```

but getting:

```
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [filter] to value "org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter".
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs for [PropertyConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html):

> The PropertyConfigurator does not
>   handle the advanced configuration
>   features supported by the
>   DOMConfigurator such as support for
>   Filters, custom ErrorHandlers, nested
>   appenders such as the AsyncAppender,
>   etc.

I suggest you use an XML file to set it up instead.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a filter for this.

log4j.appender.EMAIL.Threshold=FATAL

Comment: Threshold is not working with log4j version log4j-1.2.16.jar. Any help

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you added the apache log4j extras to your project. Try adding a numeric after filter, like this:

`log4j.appender.EMAIL.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter`

Not sure if/where this is documented but I saw this somewhere gave it a shot and it worked.

If you don't have apache log4j extras and you're using maven just get the snippet from mvnrepository and add it to your pom.xml then rebuild maven (mvn eclipse:eclipse).